# Can a UIView object act as UITableView object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I am currently learning iOS development from a book. There is one code which confuses me and on which I need help.

So, the instructions in the book ask the reader to create a single view application first. Then, it says to drag a `TableView` and drop it onto the `ViewController`. Then while selecting the table view, enter 1 for the Tag value in the View section of the Table View object.

After this, it says to access the implementation file which acts as controller to the `ViewController` in the storyboard and it adds some codes. Until then, everything is fine for me....

However, at one point, it asks the reader to add the following code:

```
UITableView *tableView = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

This is the code on which I need help. I understand what it is trying to do. It is selecting the Table View located in the View Controller but does that not return an object of the type `UIView`? How can an object of the type `UIView` be equal to a `UITableView` object? I thought that it is an object of the type `UITableView` which could 'act' as a `UIView` type since `UITableView` is the grandchild of `UIView`....

Also, what is the purpose of the `(id)` part? Is it casting the `UIView` to an object of the type `id`? Why is this necessary?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok. `[self.view viewWithTag:1]` will return a `UIView` and here as you know that the tableview has tag 1, it will be returned. The confusion you have is that if thats a view then how can we assign it to a tableview. The thing is `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIView`. So you can assign any subview of `UIView` from that method.

The purpose of `id` is that, `id` means that you dont know what is going to be returned. `id` means any type.

So to explain in brief `(id)[self.view viewWithTag:1]` means the UIView that is being returned from the method is basically casted into "any object". This is done as user might confuse or forget and assign any other object with tag 1.

The more subtle snipped would be `UITableView *myTableview = (UITableView *)[self.view viewWithTag:1]`. This is more subtle as you already know the view with tag 1 is a tableview. But casting it to id is more "safe".

Hope could clear your confusion. Check the Class hierarchy for a better understanding [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKit_Framework/)

## EDIT

As Paulw11 pointed it out, casting into id is not safe strictly in this sense, as we are assigning it into a tableview, so in situations when you dont know what the object would be of class, you assign it into id, you can cast it into id in that time.

eg. `id dontKnowWhatObject = (id)[self.view viewWithTag:1]`

Comment: I would argue that using (id) isn't any safer since the result is assigned to a variable of type UITableView, so the type of the returned object is assumed anyway. Better to use the correct cast as you showed in your answer than id which basically just avoids a warning.

Comment: ^yes true about that. But casting into id would be safer when you are assigning to an id rather than a `uitableview` unlike this example.
let me edit the answer to make your point valid in a sense.

Comment: OK. Makes sense to me. I was initially thinking that it would have been better to use (UITableView *) rather than (id).